# View Transitions troubleshooting

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sqlite

I'm loading an image from an async database in every view of my app.

I'm using a view transition in Pop/PushView to change between views.

Problem: The image loads after the ViewTransition is complete, instead of before.

Solutions?

And the code:

```
private function NextView():void
{
selectStmt = new SQLStatement();
selectStmt.sqlConnection = conn;
var sql:String = "SELECT rowid, List, CAST(Image AS ByteArray) AS Image FROM Data 
WHERE rowid = @nextPage" ;
selectStmt.parameters["@nextPage"] = nextPage;   // Id of next record
selectStmt.text = sql;
selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
selectStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);
selectStmt.execute();

navigator.pushView(NextView, nextPage, null, nextViewTransition);
}

private function selectResult(event:SQLEvent):void
{       
selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, selectResult);
selectStmt.removeEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, selectError);

var result:SQLResult = selectStmt.getResult(); 

if (result.data != null) 
{
    resultArray = new ArrayCollection(result.data);
    rowid = result.data[0].rowid;
    listName = result.data[0].List;
    viewImage = result.data[0].Image; 
    pageImage.source = viewImage;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only push the view *after* you get the image from the db?

Comment: That's the obvious problem, right? So I tried pushing from a few different methods but I've had the same luck. What kind of event listener can I put on an image source changing? The mxml has a change property, as well as a few others that would be useful, but the pushViews are getting called in ActionScript. I'm trying to recycle that same code for use with both push and pop calls.

Comment: well, you have your 'result' function right? change the view after that?  Also, I believe the 'complete' event is dispatched from the Image component when the image is done loading.